# Batch script get databases name into variable

Tags: batch-file

I had ran my script to get the databases name into variable to check some conditions. but when I ran the script and test echo out of the variable it doesn't work. Please look at my coding:

```
%mysql% -u%dbuser% -p%dbpass% -s -N -e "SHOW DATABASES" | FOR /F "usebackq" %%D IN (`findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema mysql test"`) DO SET dbname=%%D echo %dbname%
```

The result is:

```
SET dbname=mydatabasename echo
```

I had put a command `SETLOCAL` on the header of script but no luck.

`@echo off`

`SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

Can anyone help me to get the correct command?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two separate commands on the same line the way that you've written them. You have two options:

Option 1: Use parentheses to create a code block

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq" %%d in (`findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema mysql test"`) do (
    set dbname=%%d
    echo !dbname!
)
```

Note that you need to enable delayed expansion and use `!` instead of `%` to call variables that get set inside of code blocks.

Option 2: Use a `&` to join the two commands.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%d in (`findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema mysql test"`) do set dbname=%%d&echo %dbname%
```